Why couldn't I correctly use the spherical coordinate system when calculating this surface intergral?
The problem I've been trying to solve is this:

Consider sphere surface $\Sigma: x^2+y^2+z^2=2ax(a \gt 0)$, find surface integral: $\iint_{\Sigma}(x^2+y^2+z^2)dS$.

What I tried to do is to first convert x, y, z coordinate into spherical coordinates:
$$
x = r\sin\phi\cos\theta\\
y = r\sin\phi\sin\theta\\
z = r\cos\phi\\
$$
Then substitute the x,y,z coordinates to the spherical coordinates:
$$
I=\iint_{\Sigma}(x^2+y^2+z^2)dS = \iint_{\Sigma}2axdS\\
I=2a\cdot2\cdot\int_0^
{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int_0^\pi r\cdot\sin\phi\cos\theta\cdot r^2 \cdot \sin\phi d\phi
=4a\cdot\int_0^
{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int_0^\pi r^3\cdot\sin^2\phi\cos\theta d\phi
$$
Then solve for r based on the sphere equation, and substitute it into the integral:
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2=2ax=2a\cdot r\sin\phi\cos\theta\\
r=2a\sin\phi\cos\theta\\
r^3=8a^3\sin^3\phi\cos^3\theta\\
I=4a\cdot\int_0^
{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int_0^\pi 8a^3\cdot \sin^5\phi\cos^4\theta d\phi=
32a^4\cdot\int_0^
{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int_0^\pi \sin^5\phi\cos^4\theta d\phi=\frac{32a^4\pi}{5}
$$
The correct answer is however $8a^4\pi$. I couldn't recogniz the error in my deduction, could anyone give a hint? Thanks.

@Jon @Kurt Thanks for the hints. I've noticed this in some solutions to this question. However, I've come to think about two other integrals:
Consider the same sphere: $\Sigma: x^2+y^2+z^2=2ax(a \gt 0)$
Using the method I applied to this question, I could work out the volume and surfave area of the given sphere:
$$
V=2\cdot \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d\theta \int_0^{2a\sin\phi\cos\theta}
r^2\cdot \sin\phi dr=\frac{4}{3}a^3\pi\\
S=2\cdot \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d\theta \int_0^\pi r^2\sin\phi d\phi\\
r=2a\cdot \sin\phi\cos\theta\\
S=2\cdot \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d\theta \int_0^\pi 4a^2\sin^3\phi\cos^2\theta d\phi=\frac{8}{3}a^2\pi\\
$$
Notice that the volume was correct whereas the surface area was wrong. I suspect that the problem has something to do with substituting $r$ with $2a\cdot \sin\phi\cos\theta$.

The surface $\Sigma$ is not a sphere around the origin. What is it? Another hint.

The surface integral will depend on how "wriggly" the surface is, which is not captured by $r^2\sin\phi$.  Go back to the definitions to find the correct jacobian.  Informally, you can find $dS=J(\phi,\theta)d\phi d\theta$ under the assumption $r=r(\phi,\theta)$ and $J$ will depend on the partials of $r$.

Reading the edits I have absolutely no idea what you are doing with those "plugins" of $r,.$ The only correct method is to take @Jon's parametrization and calculate \begin{align*}
\int_\Sigma &2ax,dS=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}2a\underbrace{(a+a\sin\phi\cos\theta)}{x},\underbrace{a^2\sin\phi,d\phi,d\theta}{dS}\end{align*} which leads to the result they told you that it is correct.

Thanks a lot @Kurt, sorry for the ambiguity. What I mean by "plugging in" is simply to substitute variables. In my case, I sense that substituting r with 2asin\phicos\theta is somewhat wrong. I get the correct method now btw, thanks.

It isn't "somewhat wrong". It is obviously totally wrong. I hope you understand why you now get the correct result.

It looked indeed odd to me when I found a variable "r" in the integral which did not get integrated. But then I assumed that $r=r(\theta, \phi), r=2asin\phi cos\theta$ which was derived from the equation itself. May I ask where exactly did I go wrong here? @Kurt

I think it is better to learn why the correct formula is the one I wrote. That should be the first principle and not the mechanical manipulation of symbols.

@Kurt Okay, thanks. I'll try to learn that one.

Note that the equation of the sphere can be rewritten as
$$
(x-a)^2+y^2+z^2=a^2.
$$
This means that the center is at $(a,0,0)$ and the radius is $a$. Therefore, your spherical coordinates would be better written as
$$
x=a+a\sin\phi\cos\theta \quad y=a\sin\phi\sin\theta \quad z=a\cos\phi.
$$

Thanks Jon, I've added in the question and suspect that there's something wrong when I tried to substitute r with 2asin\phicos\theta.
